# Book where main character possessed psi power and sported a mohawk

Tags: story-identification, soft-sci-fi

I'm looking for a science fiction book about a teen with psi powers. I read this book way back in the 90s. I remember the kid having headaches until he was taught to use his powers by a gang of kids who sported mohawks. He traveled to parallel worlds and was controlled by a mind parasite. His father was able to control the wind.

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details.

Answer (score 5):

I've read this novel: *[*Warchild*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/184791.Warchild)* by Richard Bowes, which has a sequel entitled *[Goblin Market](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/429471.Goblin_Market)*. The Riders described in the blurb refers to mind parasites which don't have physical forms (so they have to "ride" beings which do). The protagonist has a mohawk and gets temporarily possessed by one.

> In every quadrant in time telepathic and mysterious beings are
> manipulating the very fabric of the universe, seeking ultimate
> control. On one world, the wise leader of the Republic valiantly tries
> to contain the atrocities of marauding, savage hordes. On another,
> people are bought and sold as chattel in the dreaded Goblin Market.
> And everywhere, the insidious influence of the Riders is felt, as they
> steal and enslave human minds. But in the void of the Time Lanes, a
> boy with telepathic powers he has yet to discover has entered the
> portal where all world are joined. Young and untried, a loner with
> much to learn, he must now become the legendary Warchild, if the
> universe is ever to survive...

You can see the protagonist's mohawk on the covers.

[image]