# Cyberpunk alternative worlds through television

Tags: story-identification, books, parallel-universe, cyberpunk

What i remember of the book shows a cover with a young man wearing a visor and a metal mohawk.

The story describes the main character as someone who watches TV for the government and he's able to watch a lot of tv shows on a lot of channels simultaneously taking in more information than anyone else. Then he retires after having his brain burned out and goes back home.

The kicker is that the TV programs come from parallel earths. Based on this information where it's picked up by nearly every TV on earth technology advances thanks to educational programs and commercials for products nobody's ever invented before. I especially remember them talking about subway trains that can go through stone.

Another is that with the knowledge that a revolution in an alternative world was successful a revolution in this world was inspired by it, so the political climate is all over the place.

What else i can remember about the Main Character is that he was looking at a catalog looking up what kind of mohawk he wanted when he went back to his gang.

Comment: Mohawks you say? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/167557/book-where-main-character-possessed-psi-power-and-sported-a-mohawk

Comment: @Valorum: I just identified the novel sought after in the other thread as WARCHILD by Richard Bowes. the story of WARCHILD does involve parallel worlds and the protagonist has a mohawk (a normal one, but a metal one) but none of the other details match.

Comment: An interesting book, but not the one I'm looking for. Thanks anyway. No, only the televisions pick up programmings from Alternate worlds. As far as I know there's no human travel at all.